# Firebase Messaging Flutter - Decrypt the notification body

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having a situation with Firebase Messaging in flutter. I need to decrypt the notification body - which is an encrypted chat message - before displaying it. I was able to do it on the foreground notifications, but not on the background and terminated ones.

I tried decrypting it on

```
FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) => myHandler)
```

and on

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(myHandler)
```

but it doesn't seem to run through this code.